# Difference between kvm used for x86 and Kvm for powerpc?

Tags: x86, linux-device-driver, virtualization, kvm, powerpc

I am new to Linux Kernel’s Virtualization component KVM and wanted to know the difference between kVM implementation for PowerPc and KVM implementation for x86.

As I understand kVM implementation in architecture dependent and on x86 side its uses Intel's
virtual machine extensions but not sure what CPU virtualization extenstion it uses on powerpc (e500) side?

Also,would any one help in knowing what is basic idea behind initializing VCPU's in kvm_main.c?